# save image in photo album when button click in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, photolibrary, save-image

in My Application there is one galary. 
i dont know what to put in image(UIImage *image) part of the UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum Method and I wann save image in iphone photo album. I am using this code

```
- (void)savePhoto
{
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(((IndicatorImageView *)[self._imageViews objectAtIndex:_selectedImage])._imageView.image, nil, nil, nil);

}
```

but it shows this error...

> 2012-10-26 18:48:00.596 PhotoGallery[2683:15203] -[GalleryItemView
>   _imageView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8e7cc90 2012-10-26 18:48:00.665 PhotoGallery[2683:15203] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[GalleryItemView _imageView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x8e7cc90'
>   *** First throw call stack:

Please help me if u know this...
thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)savePhoto
{
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(((IndicatorImageView *)[self.imageViews objectAtIndex:_selectedImage]).image, nil, nil, nil);
}
```

If your array `self._imageViews` contain imageViews , why you try to access `_imageView`again??

also , Is `_imageViews` a property? use `self.imageViews` is better.

Comment: i solved this months ago but then also you told right thing. so i am accepting your answer for others..

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(YOUR_IMAGE(UIImage), self, @selector(finishUIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
```

Comment: Thanks bro... but the question is UiImage is placed in another class and in this class i have to get it... so please write the syntex or link to give that...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you need.  You need to pick the imageview.image.....not the actual image variable.

```
- (IBAction)saveImageButton:(id)sender {
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(_processedImageView.image, nil, nil, nil);
}
```